# How to fix the "Create role error" on Cloud9 when running "ask deploy" (Alexa Skill Kit)?

Tags: cloud9-ide, alexa-skills-kit, cloud9, aws-cloud9

I want to use an Amazon Could9 Workspace to develop an Alexa Skill using ASK.

I did follow this guide https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/set-up-credentials-for-an-amazon-web-services-account.html to create an IAM user.

The user was added to aws using "awsconfigure".

Now, while trying to deploy my skill:

```
ask deploy
```

I do receive the following error:

```
Skill Id: amzn1.ask.skill.xxx
Skill deployment finished.
Model deployment finished.
Create role error.
InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid
```

Answer (score 1):

In AWS IAM, under user, you should see what permission you have given to a particular user. For  Cloud-9, I have AWSCloud9Administrator added and seems working fine for me.

https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1#/users/
//